g++-9: error: dynamic_lookup: No such file or directory
I am trying to follow the README in this GitHub, but I get the following error when I run make:
g++-9: error: dynamic_lookup: No such file or directory

All I could find online was that one reason for the error might be that the original code was designed for macOS with clang. I am working in Pycharm on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I have never worked with g++ before, so I am struggling with resolving this issue.
